# PHP Make root directory variable accessible from anywhere?

Tags: php

I am trying to declare some sort of global variable to contain the root directory of my project (../wamp/www/myproject)

Is there a way of storing that path when the user lands on index.php, so I don't have to redeclare that variable if the user navigates through pages?

This is because I have many CSS and JS files stored and including them gets complicated when you have a deep lying file structure and alot of scripts included into various elements (header.php, footer.php, etc..).

Comment: you can make a session variable, or have a config file with /path/to/root/ and then `include()` it on every page

Comment: Is there not an object oriented way of doing it? Extracting a value from an instance of a class?

Comment: Do you want to get the full path or abbreviated of your project?

Comment: Just so I have a global reference to the project file constantly available to me

Comment: well, you can make a class that has a method that retrieves the data from an `include()` or does session var handling, if you want to do it the "object oriented" way..

Comment: on a side note.. if you're looking to get the right path for public files (css/js).. `/` is the public root as far as apache is concerned, so you can just start with `/myproject` regardless of where the user is. e.g. if you're on `yoursite.com/myproject/a/b/c/d.php`, a js script include on that page pointing to `/myproject/js/script.js` would target `yoursite.com/myproject/js/script.js`

Comment: /myproject doesnt seem to work for me every time, do you think WAMP may be to blame?

Comment: highly doubt it.. give an example of how you are using it when it doesn't work

Comment: I managed to get it to work using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. A bit long winded for my liking but i'll just store it in a session. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

This takes you to the DocumentRoot setting in the site configuration in the apache httpd.conf (or vhosts.conf) file.